# Cant connect the module and controller file to index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs, module, controls

I'm new to Angular and have a very basic knowledge . Lately I've kept running to the same problem implementing basic modules and controls into view. I've tried following youtube videos and can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

HTML

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ng-app="module">
        <head>
          <title>Angular App</title>
          <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="connect.js"></script>
         </head>
         <body ng-controller="control">
               {{message}}
         </body>
         </html>
```

ANGULAR Connect.js

```
    var app= angular.module("module",[]);
     var control= function($scope){
             $scope.message="Hello world!";
        }
     app.controller("control",control);
```

Comment: I have given answer below with plunker link if you want you can change script.js to connect.js as you required. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html ng-app="module">
        <head>
          <title>Angular App</title>
          <script data-require="angular.js@*" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
         <script src="script.js"></script>
         </head>
         <body ng-controller="control">
               {{message}}
         </body>
         </html>
```

Angular script.js

```
var app = angular.module('module', []);
app.controller('control', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = "Hello Word!!";
  });
```

You can use below link : https://plnkr.co/edit/VhW9BrZ8ukUZecCHkONp?p=preview

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, Welcome!!

Answer (score 0):

If the script name is `Connect.js`. change the script tag

```
<script src="Connect.js"></script>
```